# Read bunch of tags in SAX in QT

Tags: xml, qt, sax

I'm using a QXMLSimpleReader to parse through an XML file via SAX.

I know this goes against the principle of SAX, but is there a neat way to grab the content of a parent tag without having to reassemble it manually ?

For example, given the following XML example (not real):

```
<record>
  <person level="manager">
    <personal>
      <male/>
      <birthday>2010-12-13T20:00</birthday>
      <promotions>2</promotions>
      <salary high="200000"/>
    </personal>
  </person>
</record>
```

I would like to grab a string containing all of the personal tag, i.e.

```
<male/>
<birthday>2010-12-13T20:00</birthday>
<promotions>2</promotions>
<salary high="200000"/>
```

The thing is, SAX automatically splits everything up into atomic tags so the personal tag parses as empty.

Solutions ideally for QT 2.3 please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would by to set a flag in QXmlContentHandler::startElement if the localName is "personal" and reset it in the corresponding endElement. If the flag is set you have to write out all **startElement**s including all attributes, all **character**s and all **endElement**s.

The easier way would be forget about xml and put the xml content in a QString and extract the interesting section using QString::indexOf and QString::mid.

Comment: The personal flag method is what I meant by "reassemble it manually". Your second suggestion is to abandon XML but in my application the XML file is much larger and SAX works well with the rest.

Comment: So the answer to your question is: No, there is no way with a SAX parser to reach your goal (see also the linked questions at the right margin).

Comment: I ended up implementing the reassemble method. It works but now tags such as <male/> come through as <male></male> because QXMLContentHandler generates startTag and endTag for this type of entity. I'll accept your answer because I wanted to verify if this type of parsing was possible or not.

Comment: You could handle this by defering the writing of the start element, doing it at the next element. If the next element is an endElement, write an empty element tag. But correct handling of attributes would become more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [QXmlStreamReader](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qxmlstreamreader.html). It's not SAX, but it's fast and easy to use. As docs say:

```
QXmlStreamReader is a faster and more convenient replacement for Qt's own
SAX parser (see QXmlSimpleReader).
```

Also, Qt 2.3?!

Comment: Maybe, but it was introduced in QT 4.3. I need to run on an embedded system that's stuck at 2.3. Thanks for the pointer though.

Comment: @koan: too bad you're stuck at 2.3, it looks like 4.6 offers exactly the function you want in readElementText(IncludeChildElements): http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qxmlstreamreader.html#readElementText